# Sox - Piping output in windows

Tags: c++, audio, emulation, sox

So I am emulating a RP2A03 chip using C++, using SoX to resample and output the audio.

I can confirm that the APU itself and input pipe is working as a charm with the command following command:

```
FILE* fp = popen(".\\sox\\sox.exe -t raw -c1 -e signed-integer -b 16 -r1789800 - -t wav -c2 -r 48000 wav.wav", "wb");
...
fputc(sample, fp);
fputc(sample/256, fp);
```

Which outputs a beautiful chiptune as wav.wav, playable in MS-media player, VLC and alike.

But when I try to pipe the music to ffplay using:

```
FILE* fp = popen(".\\sox\\sox.exe -t raw -c1 -e signed-integer -b 16 -r1789800 - -t raw -c2 -r 48000 - | .\\sox\\ffplay.exe -acodec pcm_s16le -", "wb");
```

I get an error reading:

```
FAIL sox: `-' error writing output file: Invalid argument
```

I've been hard at google for hours with no luck...

I've been stuck at this for hours, since yesterday actually, and it seems like there is something crucial (or trivial?) I am overlooking, as all the examples I find use the same, or even easier methods, to write the output to stdout.

As I can actually output it to a wav with no problems what so ever, I can't help but feel a bit taunted by the software...

If anyone have any suggestions that might help, then please, please share!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using SoX 14.0.x, and downgrading to 13.0 mended my problem immediately.
Seems like output piping is broken in 14.0.x

Thanks.